# No work completion autocomplete methods for navigation in JSF?

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a question, it turns out that recently developed with the IDE Spring Tools Suite 3.4, was testing the navigation methods for the. Xhtml, but I work very well, if I see that enters the controller and attributes declared, but what does not fit is in the methods as: 
- public void ... () 
- public String .. () 
But if it comes to navigation attribute in the controller.

```
<p:commandButton value="Send" action="#{cLogin.validarAcceso}" />
```

(Does not enter the method, nor recognizes autocompletion.)

I activated the Facelest support for JSF 2.2 in my project.
The issue is that I can not create from the IDE xhtml pages, according to research what I suggest.:

Window >> Preference >> General >> Content Types >> XML >> Add file association (*. Xhtml)

But when I turn that way, I lock all the navigation from the xhtml page. 
Can anyone tell me another suggestion.

EDIT:

If you look, working navigation attributes in the controller, esgun these images:
http://i62.tinypic.com/w7hafb.png

http://i57.tinypic.com/2ylwcjm.png

[http://i60.tinypic.com/2ijkhw4.png][3]

but what does not fit is in the methods as: 
- public void ... () 
- public String .. ()

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please create a small project with instruction on how to reproduce the problem and share it.

Comment: Releases already friend, I hope your help.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Netbeans ?

Comment: Spring Tools Suite 3.4